# Rewrite url segments to get parameters nginx

Tags: url, nginx, parameters, url-rewriting, get

I'm trying for a few hours now to solve this problem, that shouldn't be that much of a headache.

I need the correct code for a nginx server to acomplish this.

I have an url like this:
https://www.example.com/share/userid/file/

And I want to rewrite it to:
https://www.example.com/share/?id=userid&key=file/

I've tried it with several solutions here in stackoverflow but none of them have worked.

I've tried this:

```
rewrite ^/share/(.*)/(.*)$ /share/index.php?id=$1&key=$2 ;
```

That works if I place an index.php file there, however I can't do that cause /share/ is a permalink, not an actual folder (wordpress). If I do this:

```
rewrite ^/share/(.*)/(.*)$ /share/?id=$1&key=$2 ;
```

I get a 404 nginx error.

It also seems that ^/share/(.*)/(.*)$ is not actually triggering the rewrite, so that must be wrong although I'm looking at the nginx rewrite docs and looks ok.

Any ideas? I also tried with try_files with no success.

Thank you

UPDATE:

OK so this works

```
rewrite ^(/share/)([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ https://$server_name/share/?id=$2&key=$3 last;
```

However for some reason if I do this it doesn't work:

```
rewrite ^(/share/)([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ /share/?id=$2&key=$3 last;
```

I had to add the $server_name to make it work, any one can explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue myself:

```
rewrite ^(/share/)([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ https://$server_name/share/?id=$2&key=$3 last;
```

I used `([0-9]+)` cause the first parameter is a integer

However for some reason if I do this it doesn't work:

```
rewrite ^(/share/)([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ /share/?id=$2&key=$3 last;
```

I had to add

```
https://$server_name
```

Regards